# Merging two binary search trees with lowest possible time complexity

Tags: python, recursion, stack, binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on a problem that is completing a function to merge two binary search trees and return a sorted array consisting of  all node values of both trees.

I have written a code that works properly but the problem is that it seems its time complexity is not low enough.

The time complexity should be O(M+N) where M and N are the sizes of two binary search trees

And the expected auxilary space shoud be O(Height of BST1 + Height of BST2 + M + N(for storing the answer))

This is the code that I've written

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.data = data
        self.right = None

def inorder_list(theroot):
    l = []
    def inorder(root):
        if root:
            inorder(root.left)
            l.append(root.data)
            inorder(root.right)
    inorder(theroot)
    return l

def merge_two_sorted_lists(list1, list2):
    res = []
    while list1 and list2:
        if list1[0] <= list2[0]:
            res.append(list1.pop(0))
        else:
            res.append(list2.pop(0))
    res += list1
    res += list2
    return res

class Solution:
    
    #Function to return a list of integers denoting the node 
    #values of both the BST in a sorted order.
    def merge(self, root1, root2):
        #code here.
        root1_list = inorder_list(root1)
        root2_list = inorder_list(root2)
        return merge_two_sorted_lists(root1_list, root2_list)
```

The function inorder_list returns a list cosists of all node values of list (sorted because its inorder traversal)

And the function merge_*two_sorted*_lists merges two sorted lists and returns a sorted list consist of all elements of both lists.

The time complexity of every inorder traversal function is O(size of the bst) and the time complexity of merge_*two_*sorted_lists is the size of the first list + the size of the second list (M+N).

My idea to create an empty stack and filling it while traversing both BTSs simultaneously but i don't know how to do it .

Is there any other algorithm that its time complexity is O(M+N)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge_two_sorted_lists` isn't O(M+N), due to the costly `pop(0)`. Just do `return sorted(list1 + list2)`.

Python's `sorted` recognizes the two sorted runs and merges them in linear time (at least in CPython, which you're most likely using, and apparently also in PyPy). Alternatively, use `list(heapq.merge(list1, list2))` or use deques and `.popleft()`, or any other way to merge in linear time.

How I might do it:

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, root1, root2):
        data = []
        def inorder(root):
            if root:
                inorder(root.left)
                data.append(root.data)
                inorder(root.right)
        inorder(root1)
        inorder(root2)
        data.sort()
        return data
```

Comment: It should be noted that `sorted` only happens to be O(n+m) here due to the properties of Python's Timsort when running on runs of sorted data. But it seems like using the built-in sort in a sorting exercise would be cheating.

Comment: @interjay I'd agree if the task were "Sort a list". But if it's just a part of a bigger task, I think it's ok. Looks like LeetCode, which is ostensibly about job interview preparation, and in a job interview, why wouldn't I demonstrate my knowledge of the language?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well and your explanations are very informative